# TexStudio is not running, showing Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error:

Tags: latex, gnome, fedora-25

Running TexStudio from terminal showing the following error, however from GUI TexStudio is not opening.

```
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:597:14: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:600:17: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:784:14: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:787:17: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1096:14: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1099:17: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2282:8: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2282:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2287:8: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2287:18: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4331:14: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4331:14: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4393:12: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4393:12: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4402:16: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4402:16: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4417:22: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4417:22: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4473:12: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4475:16: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4475:16: Expected a string.
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4523:12: not a number
(texstudio:10650): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4523:12: Expected a string.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My system runs on Fedora 25, Numix theme is installed and Gnome is the desktop environment.